# Plugin with id 'id' not found (gradle custom plugin)

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I created a simple gradle plugin inside project. According to the doc it should be fine but when I try to use it I get `Plugin with id 'show-date-plugin' not found.`
Doc I'm referring to:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html

> You can put the source for the plugin in the
>   rootProjectDir/buildSrc/src/main/groovy directory. Gradle will take
>   care of compiling and testing the plugin and making it available on
>   the classpath of the build script. The plugin is visible to every
>   build script used by the build. However, it is not visible outside the
>   build, and so you cannot reuse the plugin outside the build it is
>   defined in.

This is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
}

group 'info.garagesalesapp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    compile project(':json-display')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'project-report'
apply plugin: 'show-date-plugin'
```

This is pluging location in project:
[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not follow the documentation. The path in your quote is `rootProject/buildSrc/src/main/groovy`, but you do not use the `buildSrc` directory, but include plugin source code into your project sources. Since those sources are only build if and when the specific `compileJava` / `compileGroovy` are executed, they can not be available in the build script.

You can think of the `buildSrc` directory as a simple subproject and you can also create a `build.gradle` file there. If you do not create one, an implicit build file content will be used.

It seems like plugin ids cannot be used for `buildSrc` plugins. Plugins need to be applied by specifying the full name (with package) of the implementation class:

```
apply plugin: ShowDatePlugin
```

If your plugin works as expected, I would suggest extracting the code into a separate plugin project to achieve a better reusability.

Comment: I just did everything like you said but still got the same error. This's killing me )

Comment: It seems like plugin ids cannot be used for `buildSrc` plugins. You need to apply the plugin by its package path: `apply plugin: package.path.to.ImplementationClass`. I just tested both ways and only this one worked.

Comment: did it. didn't help. please if you have couple minutes could you take a look at my project I pushed it to github 
https://github.com/IuriiKoval/java-project

Comment: I edited my answer and added a code example. Could you try this? For the package your are using at the moment you would need to use `apply plugin: org.koko.ShowDatePlugin`. Also, for further reference, the path to the `.properties` file is wrong in your project.

Comment: tried `apply plugin: org.koko.ShowDatePlugin` didn't help

Comment: `Plugin with id 'org.koko.ShowDatePlugin' not found.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172277/discussion-between-lu-koerfer-and-iko).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, sometimes we need to go further in the documentation because it may not be as clear.

My problem was that I was not adding the buildSrc/build.gradle file, so it was not finding the plugin id:

**buildSrc/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}
```

This is in fact mentioned in the docs but way bellow other sections

Finally, it appears that the pre-compiled plugin cannot be applied at the `allprojects` configuration of the **root build.gradle**, so I needed to add it to every module build file.